# How to make inner element scroll in a fixed outer element with CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, zurb-foundation

In other words, is there someway to "detach" inner(child) elements from their outer(parent) elements? That way, when you scroll, the outer(parent) element stays the put but the inner(child) element scrolls.

Maybe this is backwards thinking, and if it is please tell me and I'll try to solve this problem from a different perspective.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I should have been more specific. The problem I'm encountering with Foundation's off-canvas side navigation panel is that it doesn't stay fixed. Given that it, necessarily, has to encapsulate `ng-scope`, I thought I could tell it to stay fixed while `ng-scope` scrolls. Problem is that when I do that everything stays fixed, even when I adjust `ng-scope`'s overflow to `auto` or `scroll`

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest example that I can think of:

```
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Example here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYedRo